# NC COM switch connected to GPIO

Tags: raspberry-pi3, gpio, relay

I have a heating control device in my home that has two inputs marked NC and M (or COM?), which I read in the documentation I can use to control/switch the state of the device (it also says the input accepts 10V..). I think it means it would accept a switch between those two terminals. It also mentions it is isolated from the mains.

Being only a mediocre RPi3 user/developer, with little hardware hacking experience, I was wondering if the RPi3 GPIOs could be directly connected to those input terminals and make me able to change the state of the device. In which case, what GPIO numbers are best, how would they connect and what is the principle of programming this as I would prefer to use node-red and its GPIO nodes or the command line.

Comment: RPi GPIO can provide a maximum of 16mA per pin, and operates on 3.3v. It probably not wise to connect directly to whatever device it is, especially you sounds don't quite know what exactly it is, a switch? a relay? and what kind?

Comment: It’s a wireless device connected to mains, but no relay, it only sends a wireless KNX-RF message to another unit when this “switch” opens (or closes).